# How to convert a hashmap into a cachable map

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

What I am referring to is the following:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

I have a hash-map currently defined as followed:

```
Map<String, String> barcodeMap = Maps.newHashMap(); //Declaring hashmap
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) // populating hashmap
 {
  barcodeMap.put(nextLine[0], nextLine[1]);
 }
```

I want my map to be implemented with the cache, where it is only stored for two hours at a time, I tried reading the examples in the link I put but I did not understand how I would change my current map. I do understand I have to populate the map then use eviction but I do not understand how I will be changing my current code.

Comment: So what did you try? What exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: I suggest you start with the example given in the link you provided.  You just need to remove the bits you don't need and change the expiry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, though I can see confusion because all of the examples they give assume you're using a CacheLoader to populate the Cache, where, if you were using a Map previously, you wouldn't be.

So, the example given is:

```
 LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

You're inserting into the map directly, and not using a loader, so remove the loading part:

```
 Cache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
   .build();
```

Don't need to be notified when an item is removed?

```
 Cache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build();
```

Don't want a fixed sized cache, and want to limit it solely on time?

```
 Cache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build();
```

And you said you wanted 2 hours, and your version is String,String, so...

```
 Cache<String, String> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
   .build();
```